# how to download python2.7 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.5 debian package?

Tags: ubuntu, bazel

I want to use [python2.7 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.5 package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/2.7.6-8ubuntu0.5) in a code repo(using bazel). In order to decouple the repo and the OS, i want to download package and repackage it and use a BUILD file to describe package so it can be used by code in the repo.

Questions:
1) How can i download this specific version of python package? simple apt-get download python2.7 on an ubuntu 18.04 fetch a wrong version for me.
2) after getting the debian package, how to repackage it? I hope to create a tarball and then used it in the repo as external dependencies

Also, i'd like to learn more about debian and apt and how does it manage packages in the system, does anyone have good reading/study materials for a beginner?

Many many thanks!

Comment: what research on subject have you done so far?

Comment: i figured out 1) by switching back to ubuntu14.04, and then apt-get download python2.7=2.7.6-8ubuntu0.4. but still feel confused about 2)